# The Biblical Hermeneutics SE site is live in public beta

Tags: discussion, site-definition, scope

http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com

I thought the community here would be interested.

It will be interesting to see how that proposal and this one co-exist.

Here are some relevant questions on their meta:

- [How can this site distinguish itself from Christianity SE?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/36)
- [Having extended hermeneutics to exegisis, where do we draw the line?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/50/36)

Comment: You couldn't have posted this at a better time. :P

Comment: @El'endiaStarman: what do you mean?

Comment: Wait a few moments and you'll see.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman: are you talking about **the cleanup**?

Comment: I am indeed. [This question](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/680/can-we-reverse-the-trend-on-low-quality-posts) makes it clear(er) that BH.SE is for exegesis and †.SE should now be for doctrine. We have more posts to come, but we're waiting on feedback to the first one.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman: I don't think that's a good way of explaining it. Exegesis is still on topic here! But only exegesis that is used to define or defend a point of doctrine. Likewise hermeneutics will be doing exegesis but stop short of dealing with the many varied points of application of the doctrines that come out of that.

Comment: @Caleb: Yeah, I gave the extremely simplified version.

Comment: My opinion: we shouldn't have this split. But we'll see how it plays out...

Comment: You're missing a *t*.

Comment: @TRiG - who? You think I should be twikis?! :)

Comment: @Wikis: *though* -> *thought*. I'm a proofreader. I can't help myself.

Comment: @TRiG: nice catch, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the best questions here on C.SE are pure biblical hermeneutics questions. Does this mean they should now be migrated over there? Personally I would hate to see that happen: the Bible is one of the key foundations of Christianity and for questions about it, even if they don't relate to doctrine/practice, to suddenly be off-topic here would be ludicrous.

Comment: FWIW, I agree. We'll have to see how it goes. The danger of having two sites is that one (or both) might not remain viable on its own.